# Instagram API pagination

Tags: php, jquery, api, instagram

I am using the below code which works well at loading all the images that match the #spproject tag. What i'd like to do is load 9 photos at a time and then either load more with ajax or just link to previous/next pages. Problem is i dont quite understand how to do it using the API, can you help?

CODE:

```
<?PHP
function get_instagram($next=null,$width=160,$height=160){

    if($next == null ) {
        $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/spproject/media/recent?access_token=[TOKEN]&count=10';
    }
    else {
        $url .= '&max_tag_id=' . $next;
    }

    //Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    //unlink($cache); // Clear the cache file if needed

    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    }else{
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }

    $result = '<ul id="instagramPhotos">'.PHP_EOL;
    if (is_array($jsonData->data))
    {
        foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value)
        {
            $result .= '<li><div class="album">
        <figure class="frame">
            <a href="'.$value->link.'" target="_blank"><i><img src="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'" alt="" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" name="'.$value->user->username.'"></i></a>
        </figure>
        <span class="count">#SPproject</span>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/'.$value->user->username.'" target="_blank"><figcaption class="name">'.$value->user->username.'</figcaption></a>
    </div></li>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    $result .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;

    if(isset($jsonData->pagination->next_max_tag_id)) {
        $result .= '<div><a href="?next=' . $jsonData->pagination->next_max_tag_id . '">Next</a></div>';
    }

    return $result;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>#SPproject - A worldwide instagram idea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var totalPhotos = $('#instagramPhotos > li').size();
            $('#result').text('Total tagged images: '+totalPhotos);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <?=get_instagram(@$_GET['next']);?>

        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

website: http://www.spproject.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON object which Instagram is returning contains a pagination variable and in turn, a "next_url" variable. next_url is the API URL you need to call to get the next page of results.

[Here is a good tutorial](http://eduvoyage.com/search-instagram-pagination.html) on pagination with Instagram.
Also, a tip for the future - don't post your API access codes on the internet...

The (revised) code below should be a good starting point for you.

```
<?PHP
function get_instagram($next=null,$width=160,$height=160){

    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/spproject/media/recent?access_token=[token]&count=9';

    if($url !== null) {
        $url .= '&max_tag_id=' . $next;
    }

    //Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    //unlink($cache); // Clear the cache file if needed

    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    }else{
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }

    $result = '<ul id="instagramPhotos">'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
        $result .= '<li><div class="album">
        <figure class="frame">
            <a href="'.$value->link.'" target="_blank"><i><img src="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'" alt="" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" name="'.$value->user->username.'"></i></a>
        </figure>
        <span class="count">#SPproject</span>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/'.$value->user->username.'" target="_blank"><figcaption class="name">'.$value->user->username.'</figcaption></a>
    </div></li>'.PHP_EOL;;
        //$result .= '<li><a href="'.$value->link.'"><img src="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'" alt="" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" name="'.$value->user->username.'" /></a></li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $result .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;

    if(isset($jsonData->pagination->next_max_tag_id)) {
        $result .= '<div><a href="?next=' . $jsonData->pagination->next_max_tag_id . '">Next</a></div>';
    }

    return $result;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>#SPproject - A worldwide instagram idea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var totalPhotos = $('#instagramPhotos > li').size();
            $('#result').text('Total tagged images: '+totalPhotos);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <?=get_instagram(@$_GET['next']);?>

        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good shout on the access code, completely slipped my mind. Removed it now :) Thanks for that. When i run the code it shows the 9 fine, however when i click next it doesnt update the photos :( here is what is shown in the address bar:

http://localhost:8888/spproject/?url=https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/spproject/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&count=10&max_tag_id=1375226444984

Comment: Ah - would be a good idea to replace `$jsonData->pagination->next_url` with `urlencode($jsonData->pagination->next_url)` and `get_instagram(160,160,$_GET['url'])` with `get_instagram(160,160,urlencode($_GET['url']))`

Comment: 2 secs, just trying it

Comment: Okay i updated the code and now it literally loads nothing lol

Comment: okay so that error was caused by the 3 ='s, removed one and we're getting there!
now i get this when i click next:
http://localhost:8888/spproject/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.instagram.com%2Fv1%2Ftags%2Fspproject%2Fmedia%2Frecent%3Faccess_token%TOKEN%26count%3D10%26max_tag_id%3D1375226444984 but it outputs it as html entities like %26 etc

Comment: I've updated the code above with a better way of doing it. I've also tested it this time & it works :)

Comment: have used your code and does look better HOWEVER. I dont know what im doing that you arent, but when i click next the url becomes http://localhost:8888/spproject/index.php?next=1375769797531 but there is literally no images on screen

Comment: API Key may have expired - Instagram has a 35 request per hour limit, try copying/pasting the `$url` into your browser and seeing what the response is :)

Comment: thnaks mate. give me 5 mins to charge laptop and i'll give it another shot

Comment: Were you able to get a new access token (and update the code accordingly)? I'm just seeing a "Total tagged images: 0" with no errors

Comment: i have literally jsut wrapped the foreach() in an if is_array. would you like me to update my original code so you can see what im working with now? As you can tell it displays nothing when you click next

Comment: How strange... add `echo '<!-- '.$next.'<br />'.$url.'-->';` just before the `$cache=` line and maybe even try uncommenting `//unlink($cache)`

Comment: I've done that mate, uploaded the new code and it's still the same. If i uncomment the unlink cache bit, it just doesnt work at all when you click next. you just get file_get_contents(&max_tag_id=1375226444984) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ahonline/public_html/spproject/index.php on line 22

Comment: Aha! I made a bit of a stupid mistake in my code - i've just updated it for you

Comment: haha it works! Thanks very much! Any idea why it doesn't load 9 images at a time each time i click next? i have to set count to 10 to get 9 on the first page for some reason, then the next page has 6 and so on. Bit weird, any ideas?

Comment: Smashing! Not sure off the top of my head, Instagram's API Documentation will contain the answer i'm sure :) http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/